# How to Select Layer by Location of Feature in PYQGIS?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, select-by-location

I'm tried to select layer by location with processing tool in QGIS python.

its working Layer to layer but how to do with feature?

Code:

```
for area in AreaLayer.getFeatures():
               
                processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {'INPUT':OtherLayer,'PREDICATE':[0],'INTERSECT':area ,'METHOD':1})
                print (OtherLayer.selectedFeatureCount())
```

Comment: Can you be so kind and explain what do you mean by *"its working Layer to layer but how to do with feature?"*

Comment: {'INPUT':OtherLayer,'PREDICATE':[0],'INTERSECT':area ,'METHOD':1} here area is the feature if i change area to AreaLayer its working

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the feature you want to use in the algorithm you just need to add this before the algorithm :

```
AreaLayer.selectByIds([area.id()])
```

Then you need to specify that you're only gonna use the selected feature in the algorithm :

```
QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(AreaLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid)
```

This code should work for you, just replace OtherLayer and AreaLayer input :

```
OtherLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("linear")[0]
AreaLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("parcelle_finale")[0]

for area in AreaLayer.getFeatures():
    AreaLayer.selectByIds([area.id()])
    processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {'INPUT':OtherLayer,'PREDICATE':[0],'INTERSECT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(AreaLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),'METHOD':0})
    print (OtherLayer.selectedFeatureCount())
```

Answer (score 1):

Less code and a more readable version:

```py
for feature in intersect_layer.getFeatures():
    sql_expression = f''' fid = {feature.id()} '''
    intersect_layer.setSubsetString(sql_expression)  # This will filter out the features in the `intersect_layer`
    processing.run("native:selectbylocation", 
    {'INPUT': input_layer,
    'PREDICATE':[0],
    'INTERSECT': intersect_layer,
    'METHOD':0})
```